# How do I set a cookie to expire after 1 minute or 30 seconds in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

How do i set my cookie to expire after 30 sec or 1 m ? 
this is my code :

```
$.cookie('username', username, { expires: 14 });  // expires after 14 days
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For 1 minute, you can use:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (60 * 1000));
$.cookie('username', username, { expires: date });  // expires after 1 minute
```

For 30 seconds, you can use:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 1000));
$.cookie('username', username, { expires: date });  // expires after 30 second
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 1000)); //add 30s to current date-time 1s = 1000ms
$.cookie('username', username, { expires: date });  //set it expiry
```

Comment: this is for 1 minute or 30 sec ?

Comment: @Chester: Tushar put a comment *right there in the code* to tell you.

Answer (score 3):

You can Use as below for `1 minute and 30 seconds`:

```
 var date = new Date();
 var minutes = 1.5;
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
 $.cookie('username', username, { expires: date });

//3.5* 60 * 1000 = 1 minute and 30 seconds
```

//For 30 Seconds

```
  var date = new Date();
 var minutes = 0.5;
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
 $.cookie('username', username, { expires: date });
```

Answer (score 3):

Source: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24592&seqNum=3

> You need to create the expiration date in seconds—not only that, but
> it has to be in seconds since January 1, 1970. You may wonder how you
> are going to figure out your expiration dates when you have to
> determine them in regard to January 1, 1970. This is where the time()
> function comes in.
>
> The time() function returns the number of seconds since January 1,
> 1970. If you want to create a cookie that expires in 30 days, you need to do the following:

- Get the number of seconds since 1970.
- Determine the number of seconds that you want the cookie to last.
- Add the number of seconds since 1970 to the number of seconds that you want the cookie to last.

Because we know that there are 86,400 seconds in a day (60 seconds x 60 minutes x 24 hours), you could create a cookie that expires in 30 days, like this:

```
setcookie("username", "chris", time() + (86400 * 30));
```

This function places a cookie on the user's browser for 30 days. Anytime during those 30 days, you can access the variable $username from within the script and it will return (in the above example) chris.

Comment: Thanks ...
so I want to expire after 1 day.
if I write this way is true for 1 day // setcookie("username", "chris", time() + (86400 * 1));