# Trying to expire of a cookie within 3 minutes

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm trying to setup a cookie for my website that will be expire within 3 Minutes but no luck with that... so I found a code for expiration within 30 days that work perfect but I'm having hard time to set it up for 3 minutes.

```
/** 
  * JS script with cookie integration for redirecting visitors to a splash page. jQuery free. 
 * 
  * @author Tyler Pearson 
  * @version 1.0 
 */ 




 var NMC = NMC || {}; 


 NMC.Splash = (function () { 


     "use strict"; 


     var daysBeforeCookieExpires = 30, //Need to change it for 3 min!!!
         createCookie = function(name, value, expires, path, domain) { 
             var cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + ";"; 
            if (expires) { 
                if (expires instanceof Date) { 
                    if (isNaN(expires.getTime())) { 
                         expires = new Date(); 
                     } 
                 } else { 
                     expires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + parseInt(expires, 10) * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); 
                 } 
                 cookie += "expires=" + expires.toGMTString() + ";"; 
             } 
             if (path) { 
                 cookie += "path=" + path + ";"; 
             } 
             if (domain) { 
                 cookie += "domain=" + domain + ";"; 
             } 
             document.cookie = cookie; 
         }, 
         getCookie = function(name) { 
             var regexp = new RegExp("(?:^" + name + "|;\\s*" + name + ")=(.*?)(?:;|$)", "g"), 
                 result = regexp.exec(document.cookie); 
             return (result === null) ? null : result[1]; 
         }, 
         readCookie = function(name) { 
             var nameEQ = name + "=", 
                 ca = document.cookie.split(';'), 
                i, 
                 c; 
             for (i = 0; i < ca.length; i += 1) { 
                 c = ca[i]; 
                 while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') { 
                     c = c.substring(1, c.length); 
                 } 
                 if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) { 
                    return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length); 
                 } 
             } 
             return null; 
       }; 


     return { 
         baseSetup: function(cookieName, splashURL) { 
             if (!(getCookie(cookieName))) { 
                createCookie("_splash-entrance", window.location.pathname, daysBeforeCookieExpires); 
                 window.location = splashURL; 
             } 
        }, 
         splashSetup: function(cookieName, expiresInDays) { 
             if (expiresInDays) { 
                 daysBeforeCookieExpires = expiresInDays; 
            } 
             var link = document.getElementById('splash-continue'); 
             createCookie(cookieName, true, daysBeforeCookieExpires); 
             if (!(readCookie("_splash-entrance") === null)) { 
                link.href = readCookie("_splash-entrance"); 
             } else { 
                 link.href = "/"; 
             } 
         } 
    }; 


 }());
```

Comment: What part of this line of code do you think you would need to change? `expires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + parseInt(expires, 10) * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);`

Comment: I tired to change that line of code but it didn't work for me:  expires = date.setTime(date.getTime() + (60 * 3000));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer here:
[How do I set a cookie to expire after 1 minute or 30 seconds in Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371826/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-to-expire-after-1-minute-or-30-seconds-in-jquery)

Here is an example of a cookie set to 3 minutes using the jQuery cookie plugin:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (60 * 3000));
$.cookie('username', username, { expires: date });  // expires after 3 minutes
```

The plugin:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Check the usage of the plugin. That should get you started.